# Query job history for TSX servers from MSX server using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-agent

I am attempting to construct TSQL queries to substitute various GUI tools provided by SQL Server Management Studio. One of these tools is the `Job Activity Monitor`, accessible through the `Object Explorer` window.

[image]

Our current database environment includes a cluster with 3 nodes(one primary and two read-only replicas), as well as a single, independent server standing next to the cluster.

For brevity, I'll call the nodes **N1, N2 and N3**, and the independent server **S1**.

Recently, we configured `Multi-Server Job Administration` for our servers, using S1 as the MSX (master) server, and N1, N2 and N3 as TSX (target) servers.

This means that SQL Agent Jobs that operate on the cluster-nodes are created and managed from S1.

TSX servers report their state, outcome etc to the MSX server, which can be
accessed using said `Job Activity Monitor`. From the `Job Activity Monitor`, the job-history of each enlisted server (TSX) can be accessed by selecting `View history`:

[image]

Which takes us to this window:
[image]

This is the information I am trying to recreate, using a TSQL query on the MSX server. I want to see the outcome and history of the jobs by all enlisted servers, similar to what is displayed by the GUI window.

I've tried digging through the job-related tables and views of the `msdb` database, but with no luck. The `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` table on the MSX server contains no history from enlisted servers, and I can't seem to find any good documentation on how else I would go about gathering it. Is this data even accessible through TSQL? Any relevant resource is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you want to see what SSMS is running, you can always fire up a Profiler/Extended Events trace and filter on your login.

Doing this from MSX master and viewing a Multi-Server's job history gets you this query:

```
SELECT null as instance_id, 
     sj.job_id,
     job_name = sj.name,
     null as step_id,
     null as step_name,
     null as sql_message_id,
     null as sql_severity,
     sjh.last_outcome_message as message,
     sjh.last_run_outcome as run_status,
     sjh.last_run_date as run_date,
     sjh.last_run_time as run_time,
    sjh.last_run_duration as run_duration,
     null as operator_emailed,
     null as operator_netsentname,
     null as operator_paged,
     null as retries_attempted,
     sts.server_name as server
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobservers                sjh
  JOIN msdb.dbo.systargetservers sts ON (sts.server_id = sjh.server_id)
  JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view     sj  ON(sj.job_id = sjh.job_id)
  WHERE sj.name = 'MULTI_SERVER_JOB_NAME'
```

Comment: That's actually a really good idea! I find the profiler quite confusing, but I'll look further into extended events for this use-case. Thank you.